# Call Java Modal function from spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new in java spring technology. I want to call getFunction in modal from java spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/category/pagination-mobile/{categoryId}/{currentCity}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> paginationMobile(ModelMap model, @PathVariable int categoryId, @PathVariable int currentCity, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Map<String, String> resp = new HashMap<>();
        List<CityProduct> cityProducts = productService.getCityProductsForCategoryForWeb(categoryId, currentCity, 15, false);
        request.setAttribute("products", cityProducts);
        request.setAttribute("categoryId", categoryId);
        System.out.println("-------------->  " + cityProducts.getPrice());
        String paginationFirstPage = getHtmlResponse(request, response, "/WEB-INF/jsp/catalog/_categoryFirst.jsp");
        resp.put("html", paginationFirstPage);
        return resp;
    }
```

**.java**

```
public class CityProduct implements Serializable {
 public CityProduct(Product p, ProductOfCity pc) {
 this.price = pc.getPrice();

}

 public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

I want to fetch all price from modal. How to fetch all price in spring controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cityProducts` is object of `List`, os you can't call `getPrice` method on `cityProdycts` object. You have to iterate over the `List` like below to fetch the price of each product using `getPrice` method.

```
for(CityProduct cityProduct : cityProducts){
    System.out.println(cityProduct.getPrice());
}
```

If you want some logic to implement over price, you can do that in the for loop.

Comment: I want to display integer number of price. Right now it is comes 1299.0000. But I want to display 1299. I am already using  <fmt:formatNumber> in jsp. can i validate in controller?

Comment: use `cityProduct.getPrice().intValueExact()` in your controller.